# Transform.translate и Add.Force

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть объект, размечен где перед где зад. Всё хорошо. Если прилагаю с нему

```
myTransform.Translate(Vector3.forward);
```

Он движется "лицом" вперёд.
Если его развернуть - движется так же лицом вперёд, т.е. меняет направление за поворотом.
Если сделать вместо просто перемещения физику

```
rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward*120)
```

(120 для того чтобы телу силы хватило. Без этого множителя он вообще не двигается. Тяжёлый)
То он двигается как двигался - т.е. сначала лицом вперёд а после разворота - лицом назад. Направление не меняется от поворота.

Вопрос - как сделать так чтобы менялось. Чтобы ригидбоди всегда двигалось лицом вперёд с заданным импульсом и силой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Движение вперёд осуществляется при помощи свойства `transform.forward` - данное свойство определяет перед объекта относительно самого объекта.

Чтобы тело двигалось всё время с определённой силой, необходимо использовать компонент `ConstantForce`. Задайте необходимые для вас значения и используйте его по предназначению.

Для того, чтобы не умножать `Vector3.forward` - необходимо настроить сам `Rigidbody`, а именно его массу. Выражение `Vector3.forward * 120` равносильно выражению `new Vector3(120, 0, 0)`.

Для большего понимания концепции физики в **Unity** необходимо пройти следующие курсы:
http://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/physics

Так же рекомендую следить за online-курсами Unity на их официальном сайте:
http://unity3d.com/ru/learn/live-training